# Performance Comparison on Regex vs. String Operations for below specific case in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, split

I'm going to extract data from a log file and going to write those data into a CSV file.

I searched about it, and I found out a lot of people trying to solve this kind of problem using regular expressions.
Below code was written by me to solve the problem.

```
def processLine(line):
    dash_split = line.split('-')
    ip = dash_split[0].strip()
    client_id = (dash_split[1]).split('[')[0].strip()
    time_stamp = (line.split("["))[1].split("]")[0].strip()
    quoted = line.split('"')
    url = quoted[1].strip()
    response_code = quoted[2].split()[0].strip()
    user_agent = quoted[5].strip()
    print(ip, "\n", client_id, "\n", time_stamp, "\n", url, "\n", response_code, "\n", user_agent)

#sample logline to be processed

line = '206.92.168.224 - defcyfefydeecgqwfcecyqw [11/Jul/2016:00:17:07 -0700] "POST /token? HTTP/1.1" 200 89 "-" "Java/1.8.0_201"rt=0.047 uct="0.000" uht="0.047" urt="0.047"'
```

Can I know whether there is any regex which is better than above string operation in performance wise?

Comment: It will be alot more readable if you would switch to regex. About performance I wouldn't know to stay, except that you can test the differences

Comment: You mean that regex is more readable than string operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible regex for this could be:

```
pattern = "((?:\d+[.]){3}\d+)\s*-\s*(\w+)\s*\[([^\]]*)\]\s*\"([^\"]*)\"\s*(\d+)[^\"]*\"-\"\s*\"([^\"]*)\".*$"
```

This does get alittle messy, especially because of the `\"`. But in my opinion, for someone with a little understanding of regex, this expression is still more clear than all the splittings...

Each parenthesis `(...)` signifies a capture group that you can later extract from a match, and this will hold your different variables. You will get it like:

```py
import re
def process_line(line):
    r = re.search(pattern, line)
    if r:
        ip, client_id, time_stamp, url, response_code, user_agent = r.groups()
    else:
        return "Error!"
```

And performing the same print as you did, gives:

```
206.92.168.224 
defcyfefydeecgqwfcecyqw 
11/Jul/2016:00:17:07 -0700 
POST /token? HTTP/1.1 
200 
Java/1.8.0_201
```

You can see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/9y3bz6/1) to see how exactly that works, and also see the timing of the operation. As to your approach, you can time it and see which is better.

Note that this pattern holds for the specific example you gave and I tried to make it as general as possible but since you didn't give more examples or more details about the structure of the strings this might fail on other inputs.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works for all my strings as well. Above demo was very useful.